# Replacing last characters with a character

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq

I can have these possible slug strings

```
my-post
my-post-2
my-post-2-3
my-post-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9

this-is-my-post
this-is-my-post-2
this-is-my-post-2-3
this-is-my-post-2-3-4-5-6-7

abc-abc-abc1
abc-abc-abc1-2    
abc-abc-abc1-2-3-4-5-6
```

They can be anything with number or no numbers at the end.

What I want to do for example take:

```
this-is-my-post-2-3
```

Then replace `-2-3` at the end with `=2=3`. So it becomes:

```
this-is-my-post=2=3
```

So is there a clean way I can do it in linq or by some string parsing or something else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to figure out the end of the string and then do a normal replace of characters:

```
Regex.Replace(slug, @"[\d-]+$", m => m.Value.Replace('-', '='));
```

Quick PowerShell test:

```
PS> $strings | %{ [Regex]::Replace($_, '[\d-]+$', {$args[0].value.replace('-','=')}) }
my-post
my-post=2
my-post=2=3
my-post=2=3=4=5=6=7=8=9
this-is-my-post
this-is-my-post=2
this-is-my-post=2=3
this-is-my-post=2=3=4=5=6=7
abc-abc-abc
abc-abc-abc=2
abc-abc-abc=2=3=4=5=6
this-is-my-2nd-post
```

Comment: if it have a string like this-is-my-post1

Comment: However, it will also change `this-is-my-2nd-post` into `this-is-my=2nd-post`.

Comment: Then it won't replace anything. If you have edge cases to worry about *then state them in your question beforehand*. We who answer only have what you give us. We can't read minds or are otherwise psychic.

Comment: Looks like the OP wants the hyphen replaced with equals only if it is preceded by a digit rather than followed.

Comment: Replaced with a different version which only will replace them at the end of the string.

Comment: Dan: No, look at the examples which clearly replace them after the last word (i.e. in a place that is *not* preceded by a digit).

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regular expression to isolate the digits at the end, and replace the dashes in it:

```
Regex.Replace(s, @"(-\d+)+$", m => m.Value.Replace('-', '='))
```

Example:

```
this-is-my-2nd-post        ->  this-is-my-2nd-post
this-is-my-2nd-post-1      ->  this-is-my-2nd-post=1
this-is-my-2nd-post-4-5-6  ->  this-is-my-2nd-post=4=5=6
```